# Codekit & Bootstrap: variables.less does not reload live

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, livereload

I am trying out Codekit with bootstrap less files and live reload feature :)

I directly edit the less files in folder "less" which will be imported in "bootstrap.less" bootstrap.less then will be compiled to "css/bootstrap.css" which is linked in the index.html.

All is working well so when I edit some code in a less-file like navbar.less and save it, the browser reloads live as expected but for some reason if I change a variable value in "variables.less" file and save it, the browser does not reload live. I have to reload manually. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced some issues with the auto reload not working if `//` comments are not placed strategically.

See if you can move any comments to new lines in bootstrap.less or just remove all of them.

Just to be sure, I'd also remove the project from codeKit and re-add it.

Since we're on the subject, you may want to consider using [Kickstrap](http://getkickstrap.com), an extension framework for Bootstrap which allows you to write your customizations in a separate layer. This way, you'll never have to edit the core Bootstrap files and can continuously keep Bootstrap up-to-date without affecting your modifications.

Comment: thanks, i will check it out..i could refine the issue a bit...when i change @navbarInverseBackground:                #0468BF;

Comment: Thanks, i will check it out. I could refine the issue a bit. When i change: 
'@navbarInverseBackground: @blue;'
to
@navbarInverseBackground: #555;
live reload works, but if i try to use another defined variable like:
'@navbarInverseBackground: @gray;'
live reload does not work :(

I also deleted the comments.

Comment: Hmm. That is odd. Have you tried contacting the developer of CodeKit